# Cannot read property 'title' of undefined when accessing nested object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read the value in `businessData[i].services[i].title` in my forEach loop but keep getting the following error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

How do I correctly read the property title in the services array?

**profileData and businessData object**

```
var profileData = [{
  id: 1,
  notifications: [{
    type: 'payment-received',
    businessId: 1,
    serviceId: 2,
    timestamp: 1455177629000,
    text: ''
  }, {
    type: 'accepted-booking',
    businessId: 1,
    serviceId: 2,
    timestamp: 1454661898000,
    text: ''
  }, {
    type: 'received-booking',
    businessId: 1,
    serviceId: 1,
    timestamp: 1454661897000,
    text: ''
  }]
}];

var businessData = [{
  id: 1,
  categoryId: 1,
  name: 'Japan Center Garage',
  services: [{
    id: 1,
    businessId: 1,
    title: 'Brake Fluid Refresh'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    businessId: 1,
    title: 'Diagnostics'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  categoryId: 1,
  name: 'Rex Garage',
  services: [{
    id: 3,
    businessId: 1,
    title: 'Coolant Refresh'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    businessId: 1
    title: 'Oil Change'
  }]
}, {
  id: 3,
  categoryId: 1,
  name: 'Mission & Bartlett Garage',
  services: [{
    id: 5,
    businessId: 1,
    title: 'MOT'
  }, {
    id: 6,
    businessId: 1,
    title: 'Summer Check'
  }, {
    id: 7,
    businessId: 1,
    title: 'Winter Check'
  }]
}]
```

**getSelectedProfile function**

```
getSelectedProfile: function(profileId) {
  var profileId = parseInt(profileId);
  for (var i = 0; i < profileData.length; i++) {
    var profile = profileData[i];
    if (profile.id === profileId) {
      profile.notifications.forEach(function(value) {
        console.log(businessData[1].services)
        if (value.type === "payment-received") {
          value.text = businessData[value.businessId].name + " has received payment for the " + businessData[value.businessId].services[value.serviceId].title + " service.";
        }
        else
        if (value.type === "accepted-booking") {
          value.text = businessData[value.businessId].name + " has accepted your booking for the " + businessData[value.businessId].services[value.serviceId].title + " service.";
        }
        else
        if (value.type === "received-booking") {
          value.text = businessData[value.businessId].name + " has received your booking for the " + businessData[value.businessId].services[value.serviceId].title + " service.";
        }
      });
      return profile;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `services[value.serviceId]` is undefined, so you are iterating through a inexistent key. Try to go step by step and you'll find the missing key

Comment: How is it non-exisent? I thought it was accessible in `profileData[i].notifications`

Comment: The iteration runs X times. In one of these times, `services[value.serviceId]` doesn't exists. You need to check `value.serviceId` and see if there is a key with that. The problem is clear: `cannot read property of 'undefined'` means that javascript cannot read a property of a undefined object.

Comment: Then why does changing it to `businessData[1].services[1].title` still yield the same error message? Shouldn't it return `Brake Fluid Refresh`?

Comment: No. It should return `Coolant Refresh`. Array keys starts from `0`, not `1`

Comment: I understand. `businessData[1]` should be `businessData[0]` in the businessData object. Not  1. This is what is causing the issue. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I was using the id in businessData as a reference point and not the actual array key. Stupid mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put services[value.serviceId-1] and for every single key as well; because Array starts from 0 index.

Comment: services: [{
    id: 1,
    businessId: 1,
    title: 'Brake Fluid Refresh'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    businessId: 1,
    title: 'Diagnostics'
  }] as there are two index 0,1 you must put ur logic for the correct one

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you please show me jsfiddle example?

Comment: No worries, I got it now!